# How do encode selecting certain cards or combinations of cards into my output layer?

Tags: deep-learning, neat

I'm currently trying to teach an AI to play the card/dice game DragonWood. I have generated a python library to handle the game rules and I have a simple deterministic algorithm to make decisions. I am trying to replace this algorithm with a trained model.

DragonWood is a game for up to 4 players and involved attacking creature/enhancement cards with a players adventurer cards and rolling dice to see if that card is captured. Creature cards give points when captured and enhancement cards give modifications to the player, for example adding a modifier to dice rolls or allowing dice to be rolled again. Whoever has the most points at the end of the game wins.

There are 5 creature/enhancement cards in the landscape at all times from a pack of 42 and the player can have a hand of up to 9 adventurer cards. The adventurer cards are of 5 suits and numbered 1 to 12 totalling 64 cards.

Each turn a player can perform the following actions:

draw a card
attack
If attacking the player can pick one of the below from their hand:

a straight
a number of cards of the same suit
a number of cards of the same value
They are then given the number of dice that match the number of cards they've selected to attack with. They roll the dice and if the total is bigger or the same as the cards defence value they capture that card.

It is this decision I am looking to replicate using the NEAT algorithm. I am having trouble designing the output layer of the neural network.

The input layer is likely to be:

a one hot encoding of the creature/enhancement cards in the landscape at that point
a one hot encoding of the adventurer cards in the player's hand
some other details of the game state.
So the input layer is 42 + 64 + 4 nodes.

I need the network to tell me what decision to do, i.e. attack/reroll and if it attacks which cards to attack with and which card to attack. My current thinking on the output layer is it would need

a one hot encoding of the card to attack
a one hot encoding of the cards to attack with,
2 nodes for the decision
so 42 + 64 + 2 nodes.

This feels like too many output nodes and also the network will need to learn to only attack with cards it has in it's hand. I was assuming I could apply a mask to the output of the players hand to enforce this.

Is this architecture valid and is there a better way to encode the decision in the output layer?